# My Django website doesn't update HTML and CSS code

Tags: html, css, django, freeze, reload

I'm building Django website and when I wrote HTML code and reload the page, it didn't make anychanges
and when I tried to change the background color to red, it didn't chnaged, even when I deleted all my code in HTML file, website stayed the same.

Usually in these situations I click inspect then left click on reload button and click "Empty Cash and Hard Reload", but this time it didn't work, and I tried ctrl + F5, and shift + F5 but it still didn't work.

[image]

Comment: did you try it in incognito mode  ? just to make sure Your browser is not  storing cache of your static files.

Comment: Is this in production? If so you might need to run the `collectstatic` command

Answer (score 0):

1. Check and ensure the css class to change the background is targeted.
2. Ensure to use load static tag
3. In your link tag, place your custom css file at the bottom, just before the closing head tag